# A simple image search app

Tags: android, android-searchmanager, google-image-search, web-search

I want to develop a simple application, that will

1. Searches images with keyword
2. Browses the images
3. Saves the images

if i can do it with Google, it would be better.

so far i found this after Googling:

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
    String term = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, term);
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception ex) {

}
```

and

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
                    "http://images.google.com/search?
                     num=10&hl=en&site=&tbm=isch&source=hp‌​
                     &biw=1366&bih=667&q=cars&oq=cars& // here q='My_search_text'
                     gs_l=img.3..0l10.748.1058.0.1306.
                     4.4.0.0.0.0.165‌​.209.2j1.3.0...0.0
                     ...1ac.1.8RNsNEqlcZc"));
startActivity(intent);
```

i have not done the coding part yet.
now the question is, is this a right way the application according to what i want?
mainly, any tutorial would be a great help for me.