# Product search on basis of image in e-commerce App

Tags: android, image

Search products on basis of image captured by camera is working in flipkart? Is there any library or API available ?

Comment: Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350328/a-simple-image-search-app)

Comment: not useful..google image search is different from this. I want to know the scenario of flipkart product search using image.  How is it working, what is the logic behind this? On Basis of color code is it possible ?